# Operating on an object heap created by Molecular

Tags: animation, transforms

I am very new to Blender, I can' find the proper way to advance in this situation.

My objective is to animate an archimedean screw operating into an heap of
objects (they can be spheres or polyhedra). There must be many of these objects (say at least 40 thousands) and the heap must have a realistic shape.

I am building the heap of objects with Molecular Script and the result is a quite realistic heap that is what I need.

My problem is, after I created the objects heap I would like to copy the final state of the simulation, that is all spheres positions, and from this time on, forget how the heap was generated, just start working on the second phase of the simulation i.e. put the screw into the heap and make it run. 
The issue is, I am not able to copy the sphere positions, with "B" to select
the region and Duplicate, the balls heap is not copied.

Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: If you want a realistic start heap, ensure that the friction is correct for the objects so that they are stationary at rest.Otherwise almost anything you do is going to upset the heap when you start the animation.

Comment: I arrived at this point today: [link](http://euriscom.it/service/test-11.blend) . In the example i am not using Molecular because it is the only way i can make a copy of the object pile. Rob, i tried to adjust frictions at best, if you know how to improve more let me know.

Comment: there is also the Deactivation section in Rigid Body settings that you can set as "Start deactivated". The objects will not do anything until something acts upon them, like your screw.

Comment: I will try "Start deactivated" Rob, thank you. I discovered Ctrl-Shift-A can be useful for copies. On the other side I decided to drop Molecular and advance only with Physics builtin into Blender. Reason: objects created by Molecular. are not subject to gravity (in some cases, not for default spheres, it happened to me using a modified IcoSphere, it seems only their center of mass is subject to gravity, but not their orientation), i would need to add an extra step just to add gravity to the heap Molecular makes.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) instead of adding comments. Also please include images of your progress as part of the text and not as external links. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)